# Усолье-Сибирское

Tags: топонимика

Правило гласит:

**"Первая часть сложносоставных топонимов должна склоняться как в сочетании с родовым термином, так и без него, если топоним русский или освоен русским языком: из Камня-Каширского, в Переславле-Залесском, в Могилёве-Подольском, в Ростове-на-Дону; в городе Петропавловске-Камчатском, в городе Ростове-на-Дону".** Вторая часть склоняется тоже, как мы видим из примеров.

Почему же тогда повсеместно пишут "В городе Усолье-Сибирское", а не "В городе Усолье-Сибирском"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос "надо ли склонять" или "почему другие не склоняют"?  На первый я бы ответила: "Надо", -- на второй: "Потому что не знают правила":)

Comment: Да, понимаю, что вопрос задала некорректно. Конечно меня интересует правильный вариант написания. Согласна с Вами) Я тоже буду склонять)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что склонять слово нужно в обязательном порядке, так как причин для другого решения просто нет - наши существительные, в том числе топонимы, являются склоняемыми априори, а несклоняемость надо обосновывать.

Когда в Грамматике-80 разбирается эта тема, там подробно рассматриваются именно различные случаи несклоняемости, например: топонимы на ОВО/ЁВО, ИНО/ЫНО, склоняемость при наличии или отсутствии приложения и др.

Особо рассматривается тема ДЕФИСНЫХ написаний топонимов, а также их сочетаний с приложениями при дефисном написании. Но что важно - речь всегда идет о ПЕРВОЙ ЧАСТИ слова, например: на острове Валааме, на Москве-реке, но в Китай-городе, у Медведь-горы (искл).

Таким образом, в качестве ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ допускается несклоняемость первого слова, а основное правило  следующее: в сложносоставных названиях с дефисным написанием СКЛОНЯЮТСЯ ОБЕ ЧАСТИ: в Переславле-Залесском, Петропавловске-Камчатском и др.

Топоним "Усолье-Сибирское" интересен своим ср.родом - этот факт выделяет его среди подобных названий. Несклоняемость топонима можно допустить только в одном случае - в профессиональной речи, когда требуется абсолютная точность передачи названия. Возможно, в нашем случае профессиональный стиль речи смешался с нейтральным стилем.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkursrub.ru%2Fcities-list.php&ei=lIEyU-vMD6SL0AW7sYCQDA& -  usg=AFQjCNEIkvPz5tBIxkzeK6xHYKKQ4TJHnA&bvm=bv.63738703,d.d2k&cad=rjt Таблица склонения городов. Здесь Усолье-Сибирское склоняется.  На той же Грамоте сказано: "Все топонимы, у которых первая часть названия имеет морфологическую примету среднего рода, охвачены тенденцией к неизменяемости: из Ликино-Дулева, в Соболево-на-Камчатке." Можно ли тут отнести Усолье к среднему роду?

Comment: таблица хороша, но нюанс в том, что без родового слова они всегда склоняются. А вот когда появляется родовое слово.....

Comment: Здесь опять же речь идет о несклоняемости первой части, что становится характерным признаком топонимов ср. рода на ОВО/ЁВО, ИНО/ЫНО. А их несклоняемость, возможно, связана с необходимостью различения парных вариантов: город Пушкин - в городе Пушкине, город Пушкино - в городе Пушкино.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то здесь принято ссылки давать на правила.

Не знаю, где Вы именно такую формулировку взяли.
Есть другая, "Справка" на Грамоте неоднократно её давала:

*Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом обычно не склоняются, когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают.*

http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_455284

Это вполне наш случай. Город - мужского рода, Усолье-Сибирское - среднего.

Правда, на той же "Грамоте" есть оговорка:

*когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают: на реке Енисей, у реки Хопёр, в деревне Парфёнок (однако это замечание не относится к сочетаниям со словом город, поэтому правильно: в городе Туле, из города Москвы; о целесообразности употребления здесь самого слова город см. ниже).*
http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90

Но это тоже, видимо, не универсальное правило.

Ну и надо сказать, что в сети большой разнобой:

"в городе Усолье-Сибирское"
Результатов: примерно 512 000

"в городе Усолье-Сибирском"
Результатов: примерно 601 000

Так что еще бабка надвое сказала, как именно "повсеместно пишут".
**(==================================)**
31.03.2014
Получен ответ от "Справки".

Вопрос № 274160    
Здравствуйте!

Возник вопрос со склонением города Усолье-Сибирское в сочетании с родовым словом.
"В городе Усолье-Cибирское" или "В городе Усолье-Cибирском"?
В других падежах вообще до четырех вариантов:
"Из городе Усолье-Cибирского", "Из городе Усолье-Cибирское", или "Из города Усолья-Cибирского", "Из города Усолья-Cибирское"?

Рекомендации "Справки" и "Письмовника" неоднозначны, хотелось бы иметь ссылку на конкретное правило.
Чеширский Бегемот

Ответ справочной службы русского языка 
Сначала о склонении без родового слова город. Согласно словарям русского языка (см., напр.: Русский орфографический словарь РАН / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – 4-е изд., испр. и доп. – М., 2012; Агеенко Ф. Л. Словарь собственных имен русского языка. М., 2010), склоняются обе части этого названия: Усолье-Сибирское, Усолья-Сибирского.

При употреблении в сочетании со словом город нет причин не склонять это название. Несовпадение рода обобщающего нарицательного слова и географического названия не влияет на склоняемость топонимов в сочетании со словом город. Восстановить исходную форму при склонении достаточно легко. Следовательно, нужно склонять: из города Усолья-Сибирского, в городе Усолье-Сибирском.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_456911

Ну собственно, не вижу, что еще обсуждать.

Comment: "Географические названия, употребляемые в сочетании с родовым словом, обычно не склоняются, если:

название по своей форме соответствует множественному числу: в городе Великие Луки, в городе Бережаны;
род обобщающего термина не совпадает с родом имени собственного: в селе Углянец, на озере Байкал.
Последнее не распространяется на сочетания со словом город. Правильно: из города Самары, в городе Москве. Вариант в городе Москва не соответствует литературной норме".

Comment: Ссылки будем давать?

Comment: так в том и дело, что правила не объясняют каждый конкретный случай.... 
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1575843
Да, сейчас вижу, что название употребляется и так, и эдак.. Странно, но до этого почему-то поисковики выдавали исключительно несклоняемый вариант)))

Comment: Ссылку надо давать, чтобы проверить источник, которым Вы пользуетесь.

Comment: какая разница, все источники используют какие-то общепринятые правила из авторитетных словарей и справочников, проверенных временем.
на той же Вики есть примечание: "При составлении текста использованы материалы справочно-информационного портала ГРАМОТА.РУ (gramota.ru)".

Comment: Разница в том, что недостоверные источники тут не рассматриваются как аргумент, а достоверные проверяются на предмет из правильного понимания цитирующим.  
  
Кстати, Ваше "правило" в вопросе, строго говоря не имеет прямого отношения к вопросу. там говориться о склонении первой части сложных топонимов, а не склонении вообще. Так что оно вообще не совсем тут неуместно.

Comment: я ценю Вашу любовь к определению достоверности источников, но это не приблизило меня к пониманию того, как правильно писать Усолье-Сибирское))

Comment: Зато Вас приблизил к счастью ответ "потому, что не знают правила".   
Вот он-то точно дает ответ, как надо. )))